# Vagrant up issues while configuring vagrant with azure

Tags: azure, vagrant

I am configuring Vagrant and azure in windows machine. while running vagrant up command facing below issue

**There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the following errors and try again:
Microsoft Azure Provider:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: vm_image**

If i am running the same command by disable the Vm_image in vagrant file faced below issue

```
**"body": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"NotFound\",\r\n    \"message
```

\": \"Artifact: VMImage was not found.\"\r\n  }\r\n}",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "content-length": "99",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "expires": "-1",
      "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
      "x-ms-request-id": "553a43ab-efe6-4250-9b6d-9ab5aa9493f3",
      "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
      "x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads": "14996",
      "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "b5f9cee2-6dfc-4e89-abf7-72d2cca84ff1",
      "x-ms-routing-request-id": "SOUTHEASTASIA:20170103T072604Z:b5f9cee2-6dfc-4
e89-abf7-72d2cca84ff1",
      "date": "Tue, 03 Jan 2017 07:26:04 GMT",
      "connection": "close"
    },
    "status": 404
  }**

Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'azure'
  #config.vm.box_url = 'https://github.com/msopentech/vagrant-azure/raw/master/dummy.box'

  # use local ssh key to connect to remote vagrant box
  #config.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
  config.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
    # use Azure Active Directory Application / Service Principal to connect to Azure

    # each of the below values will default to use the env vars named as below if not specified explicitly
    #azure.mgmt_certificate = 'enterprise_dev-test-1-2-2017-credentials.pem'
    #azure.mgmt_endpoint = 'xxxxxxx'
    azure.subscription_id  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    azure.tenant_id = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
    azure.client_id = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
    azure.client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    #azure.vm_image='a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Win2K8R2SP1-Datacenter-20161214-en.us-127GB.vhd'
    azure.vm_name = 'box01'
    #azure.tcp_endpoints = '3389:53390'
  end
  config.ssh.username         = 'vagrant'
  #config.ssh.private_key_path = 'C:/Users/skannan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key'
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo hello"
  #config.vm.synced_folder "./vagrant", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.17.1.100", type: "dhcp"
end
```

Comment: What do you think vm_image should do? There is no such option, closest being vm_image_urn, but what you are supplying does not look right. See https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure

Comment: @DavidHutchison thank you. I tried the link which you gave.VMImage was not found issue occurs while vagrant up.Should i mention vm_image_urn or not? then How the VM will generate?

Comment: @DavidHutchison while running with vm_image_urn facing below issue

%userprofile%/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/azure_mgmt_compute-0.2.
1/lib/azure_mgmt_compute/virtual_machine_images.rb:42:in `get': offer is nil (Ar
gumentError)

Comment: I've never used azure with vagrant, just pointing you at the docs. If everything is up to date and not working following the documentation I'd suggest you create an an issue on the GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that you are requesting an image that isn't available, or available in your region. A common root cause of this is following outdated documentation! Try

```
az vm image list
```

And pick one from the ones